# How to update a column with another tables columns value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables "basket_products" and "products". I want to update "products" table's "adet" column with "basket_products" "adet" column. And i want to update rows where basket_products.urun = products.urun.
I want to use this code and getting error : "The multi-part identifier "basket_products.urun" could not be bound."

```
update products
    set adet = adet - (
        select basket_products.adet
            from basket_products
                inner join products
               on products.urun = basket_products.urun) 
   where products.urun = basket_products.urun
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Thank you. ı could not find topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

update p
set p.adet = bp.adet
from products p
    join basket_products bp
        on p.urun = bp.urun